# how to select table data with different values of single column in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

following code is about getting the products from my db table using codeigniter sql queries.i am getting products of a row by limiting up to 4 products and by applying where condition of products less than cost of 900 but i am not getting how to get the products less than 900 but with different prices in each item. this means if once product 0f 500 is fetched it should not fetch 500 again it should go for another product by the help of product_id DESC. Explain me the logic of query how i should write

```
public function byPrice()
    {
        $query = $this->db->limit(4)
                          ->where('pro_cost<', 900)
                          ->get('products');
        return $query;
    }
```

Comment: Please post your table stricture with some simple data. So I can help for your problem.

Comment: what's the status of this question, is it still open or solved? you only commented under one answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Q="SELECT DISTINCT `pro_cost` FROM `products` WHERE `pro_cost` < 900"; 
$result=$this->db->query($Q)->result();
```

Comment: this answer should probably be deleted, you posted 2, the other one being https://stackoverflow.com/a/48340046/1415724

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where('cost < 900', NULL)->group_by('id')->group_by('cost')->get('product')
```